# Recursive Palidromes

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a recursive function for palidromes. I get a correct answer when I test the string when no command arguments are inputted. When when there is a command argument. It keeps returning false even thought its true. What did I do wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool palindrome(string word);
string formatString(string s);

int main(int argc , char * argv[])
{
if(argc < 2)
{
string inputString;
int last = inputString.length()-1;
cout << "Welcome To My Palidrome Tester!" << endl;
cout << "Please Enter A String To Test if it is A Palidrome: ";
getline(cin, inputString);
//testForPalindrome(inputString);
string newW = formatString(inputString);
//cout << "It is a palindrome" ? (palindrome(newW) == true) : "It is Not a palidrome";
if(palindrome(newW) == true)
    cout << "It is a palindrome" << endl;
    else
    cout << "It is not palindrome" << endl;
}
else 
{
string commandStr;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    commandStr += argv[i];
}
string newW = formatString(commandStr);
if(palindrome(newW) == true)
    cout << "It is a palindrome" << endl;
    else
    cout << "It is not palindrome" << endl;

}
return 0;
}
bool palindrome(string word)
{
int length = word.length();

string first = word.substr(0,1);
string last = word.substr((length - 1), 1);

if (first == last)
{
    word = word.substr((0 + 1), (length - 2));
    if (word.length() <= 1) return true;  // Problem line?
    palindrome(word);
}
else
    return false;
}
string formatString(string s)
{
 string p;
size_t position = s.find(' ', 0);
while(position != string::npos)
{
    s.erase(position,1);
    size_t newPosition = position+1;
    position = s.find(' ', newPosition);
}
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
{
    if(ispunct(s[i]))
    {
        s.erase(i,1);
    }
    if(isupper(s[i]))
    {
        s = tolower(s[i]);
    }
}
return s;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string inputString;
int last = inputString.length()-1;
```

You are taking string's length too soon. Change to

```
string inputString;
cout << "Please Enter A String To Test if it is A Palidrome: ";
getline(cin, inputString);
formatString(inputString);
int last = inputString.length() - 1;
if (recursionPalindrome(inputString, 0, last) != 0)
    cout << "It is a Palindrome" << endl;
else
    cout << "It is not a palindrome" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems return false with print "Palindrome", while it should be "not a palindrome" from recursionPalindrome logic ?

```
if(recursionPalindrome(inputString,0,last) == 0)
    cout << "It is a Palindrome" << endl;
else
    cout << "It is not a palindrome" << endl;
```

Comment: sorry could you specify what you mean

Comment: for Palindrome string like "abcba", it will return true from your recursionPalindrome function, but after you compare it with 0, it will return false, which leads to print "it is not a palindrome"

Comment: Hey I was able to get it working for the if (argc < 2) but when I type a string in the command line that is a palidrome it returns false. Any reason why?

Comment: you should check your output from formatString, I am not sure what it means. However, if you promise input of recursionPalindrome is palindrome string, it should work, so problem must happen in formatString

Comment: Oh It copies only one character from the array for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    commandStr += argv[i];
}

Comment: When I type a space in, my string doesn't receive the whole string??